# Find the value of F $(\frac{1.5}{F})^2 +cos^2 (75)+ (\frac{1.25}{F})^2 = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the value of F $(\frac{1.5}{F})^2 +cos^2 (75)+ (\frac{1.25}{F})^2 = 1$ Im tryingnto practice my algebra but cant get it. The answer is 2.02  I tried to use shift solve in my computer and it shows 2.02

Comment: If you multiply the equation through by $F^2$ and collect terms, you'll see that you just have a quadratic equation, so the quadratic formula will give you the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

$(\frac{1.5}{F})^2 +cos^2 (75)+ (\frac{1.25}{F})^2 = 1$

$(1.5)^2+F^2\cos^2(75)+(1.25)^2=F^2$

$(1.5)^2+(1.25)^2=F^2-F^2\cos^2(75)$

$(1.5)^2+(1.25)^2=F^2(1-\cos^2(75))$

$(1.5)^2+(1.25)^2=F^2(\sin^2(75))$

$\frac{(1.5)^2+(1.25)^2}{\sin^2(75)}=F^2$